Dubious error message related check with borg backup (borgmatic)
Running borg backup (using borgmatic), I got the error message:
Ignoring check_last option, as "archives" or "data" are not in consistency checks
Ignoring consistency prefix option, as "archives" or "data" are not in consistency checks

What does that mean? What should I do? TIA!
